# Convert CSV to UTF-8

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv, utf-8, export-to-csv

How can I convert CSV to UTF-8?

I have a code that accept file, then it will convert to JSON.
The thing is, I need to manually convert the CSV file to UTF-8 first in order to convert it into JSON.
I'm using a Japanese characters for the regex.

```
  const Upload = () => {
    var fileUpload = document.getElementById('fileUpload')
    var summary = document.getElementById('summary')
    var json = document.getElementById('json')
    if (typeof FileReader !== 'undefined') {
      var reader = new FileReader()
      summary.innerHTML = ''
      json.innerHTML = ''
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        generateData(e.target.result)
      }
      reader.readAsText(fileUpload.files[0])
    }
  }

  const generateData = (res) => {
    var addressList = []
    var regex = //
    var results = res.split('\n')
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var address = results[i].replace(/"/g, '').split(',')
      if (address.length >= 8) {
        addressList.push(address[6] + address[7] + address[8])
      }
    }
    const result = addressList.reduce((accumulatedData, data) => {
      const isValid = regex.test(data)
      accumulatedData[data] = isValid
      return accumulatedData
    }, {})
    var summary = document.getElementById('summary')
    summary.innerHTML = `<label><b>Summary (valid):</b></label> ${
      Object.values(result).filter((d) => d).length
    } / ${Object.keys(result).length}`
    setAddressTestCase(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4))
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV is a data format and UTF-8 is a character encoding.

So, you just need read the file in a correct way.

I found this in Mozilla:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText

You can set encoding as below:

```
    reader.readAsText(fileUpload.files[0], 'UTF-8')
```

Comment: Does UTF-8 still apply if I have this characters `旭川|伊達|石狩|盛岡|奥州|田村|南相馬|那須塩原|東村山|武蔵村山|羽村|十日町|上越|富山|野々市` ?

Comment: I used `reader.readAsText(fileUpload.files[0], 'Shift_JIS')` and it's now working. Thank you very much!!